# What replaces Components.lookupMethod in the future?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Looks like `Components` object is deprecated, I got `The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.` with firefox 20.

Already checked [online documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components_object), looks like it's not up-to-date, it doesn't mention anything of that.

So, what replaces that in the future? All I need is to call `Components.lookupMethod`

Comment: Good question.  How exactly do I keep using api's that are useful without this error popping up everywhere?!!

Answer (score 0):

What is deprecated is the accessibility of `Components` from content code. Extensions are not affected.

Comment: Where did @warl0ck say the code in question was in an extension?

Comment: It is implied by the firefox-addon tag